# too many HTTP redirects, Google Drive, iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I have integrated my iOS application with [the Google Drive iOS API](http://developers.google.com/drive/ios). But while downloading files, it throws the following error:

```
An error occurred: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1007 "too many HTTP redirects"
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a problem either in the Mac's networking code or in the servers. Having an http log of the problem as it occurs would likely be very helpful to diagnosing what's actually going wrong. Check this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gdata-objectivec-client/CSRFGy-S7kc). It can be a connection issue between an app and its back end.

You can also check this [blog](http://appletoolbox.com/2013/02/app-store-show-too-many-http-redirects-error-fix/) on how to fix “too many HTTP redirects” error.

> - Force the App Store app to close. To to this, click the Home button twice, tap and hold on the App Store app icon and when it starts to
>     jiggle, tap the (-)  to close it.
> - Open Settings > iTunes & App Stores and  tap your account name > View Apple ID > Enter your Apple ID password and Tap done. Quit
>     Settings and try opening the App Store again.
> - Restart your iOS device
> - Reset your device (iPad, iPhone or iPod touch) by holding the home button and the sleep/wake button at the same time for about 10 seconds
>     until you see the Apple logo and then turning turn back on.

Hope this helps!